# Doctest a private method in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, doctest

Suppose I have a python class with a method that's not useful to callers (i.e. it should be private), but it has a few corner cases so I want to do a sanity check on it (i.e. it should be unit tested).

Naively, I expected I could write a doctest:

```
class Thingy:
    ...

    def __frob(self, val):
        """
        >>> Thingy(...).__frob(-2)
        1
        """
        ...
```

But when I do so I get an error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Thingy' has no attribute '__frob'
```

Which makes sense in hindsight, but isn't very convenient.

Is there a simple way to doctest private methods, besides just making them public?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python doesn't really have *private* methods. Double-underscore names are [*mangled*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers); they get the class name (with a leading underscore) prepended to their name. That's because their goal is to help avoid name clashes when subclassing, not to make them private from outside callers. Subclasses can now safely define their own `Thingy.__frob()` and it'll be kept separate from the parent class.

As such, you can manually apply the same transformation in the test:

```
Thingy(...)._Thingy__frob(-2)
```

E.g. add `_ClassName` to the start of the method name.

Just to be explicit; the feature is primarily meant to avoid name clashes between *attributes* used by subclasses. It just also happens to work for method names, as methods are essentially attributes too.

Comment: Oh, the mangling happens in a consistent way and it's kosher to refer to the resulting name? Useful.

Comment: @Strilanc: yes, the mangling is well defined and part of the language specification.